# How to force a column in excel with no values to import as a date column

Tags: excel, sas

I have an Excel file with a column that can be null or contain a date value, but when importing it into SAS I need the column to be in the format `DATE9`. As long as the column isn't completely null it works, but in some cases it will be and it imports into `SAS` as a `$CHAR1`.

The cell format is already `date` if that makes a difference.

Comment: what method are you using? (proc import, data step etc) and what version of SAS do you have?

Comment: @Keith `DATA WORK.excel_file;`  as for SAS version `SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'm assuming you have SAS Access to PC File Formats licenced then. You should be able to use the data set option DBSASTYPE, which forces SAS to use the stated data type, irrespective of how the input data looks.  In your case you want it set to numeric, then you can just use DATE9. to format it.  The code should look something like below, I'm not in a position to test it right now.

```
DATA WORK.excel_file;
set excel.spreadsheet (dbsastype=(column_name=numeric));
format column_name date9.;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to redefine the column after you have imported it.
Something like this:

```
data importedExcel(drop=suspiciousVariable2);
  set importedExcel(rename=(suspiciousVariable=suspiciousVariable2));
  attrib suspiciousVariable length=8 format=date9.;
  suspiciousVariable=suspiciousVariable2 + 0;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import with a data step instead of proc import, you can easily define the format of each variable. The following link gives a reasonably good example:http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/038-30.pdf